# How do I make the x axis start at a fixed point rather than start at 0?

Tags: r, plot, graph, axis-labels, categorical-data

I haven't used R before and have an assessment for an intro to stats class. I have found my data and I need to plot it. I am plotting Years as categories against Litres of Alcohol consumed by population each year. My data looks a bit like this:

```
  Year       Litres   Per Capita
 1960-61    67,703    9.34
 1961-62    69,408    9.38
 1962-63    71,657    9.47
 1963-64    75,590    9.79
 1964-65    79,674    10.10
 1965-66    80,866    10.00
 1966-67    85,015    10.29
 1967-68    90,946    10.78
 1968-69    95,782    11.12
 1969-70    101,951   11.58
 1970-71    105,595   11.59
 1971-72    109,156   11.58
 1972-73    116,682   12.15
```

My problem is that in trying to plot it, it's not coming up at all how I need it to. Also I'm struggling with a few things and feel like I'm doing things the long/hard way. This is what I've done so far:

```
> View(Alcohol_consumption_2013_14)
> Year <- Alcohol_consumption_2013_14$Year
> Litres <- Alcohol_consumption_2013_14$`Litres Pure Alcohol`
> Capita <- Alcohol_consumption_2013_14$`Per Capita Consumption`
> x=c(Year)
> y=c(Litres)
> plot(x,y)
  Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values
  In addition: Warning messages:
  1: In xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : NAs introduced by coercion
  2: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
  3: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
> Year <- as.numeric(Year)
  Warning message:
  NAs introduced by coercion 
> barplot(Litres,Year)
  Error in plot.window(xlim, ylim, log = log, ...) : 
  need finite 'xlim' values
> x=c(1960-61,1961-62,1962-63,1963-64,1964-65,1965-66,1966-67,1967-68,1968-
  69,1969-70,1970-71,1971-72,1972-73,1973-74,1974-75,1975-76,1976-77,1977-
  78,1978-79,1979-80,1980-81,1981-82,1982-83,1983-84,1984-85,1985-86,1986-
  87,1987-88,1988-89,1989-90,1990-91,1991-92,1992-93,1993-94,1994-95,1995-
  96,1996-97,1997-98,1998-99,1999-2000,2000-01,2001-02,2002-03,2003-04,2004-
  05,2005-06,2006-07,2007-08,2008-09,2009-10,2010-11,2011-12,2012-13,2013-14)
> plot(x,y)
```

and then this came up [graph starting at 0, rather than in year categories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngPPL.png)

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Your **x** variable is not numeric, it is a character: it includes two numbers and a hyphen. You have to convert it to numeric.

Comment: @ephy_92 If any of the answers below solved your problem, please consider accepting the answer by clicking on the `v` sign below the up- and downvote buttons, which are next to the start of the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To provide a small example (too long for a comment), consider the following:

First, your data:

```
df <- structure(list(Year = structure(1:13, .Label = c("1960-61", "1961-62", 
"1962-63", "1963-64", "1964-65", "1965-66", "1966-67", "1967-68", 
"1968-69", "1969-70", "1970-71", "1971-72", "1972-73"), class = "factor"), 
    Litres = structure(c(5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("101,951", "105,595", "109,156", 
    "116,682", "67,703", "69,408", "71,657", "75,590", "79,674", 
    "80,866", "85,015", "90,946", "95,782"), class = "factor"), 
    PerCapita = c(9.34, 9.38, 9.47, 9.79, 10.1, 10, 10.29, 10.78, 
    11.12, 11.58, 11.59, 11.58, 12.15), yr = 1:13), .Names = c("Year", 
"Litres", "PerCapita", "yr"), row.names = c(NA, -13L), class = "data.frame")
```

Let's look at `str(df)` now:

```
str(df)
'data.frame':   13 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ Year     : Factor w/ 13 levels "1960-61","1961-62",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ Litres   : Factor w/ 13 levels "101,951","105,595",..: 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 1 ...
 $ PerCapita: num  9.34 9.38 9.47 9.79 10.1 ...
```

We see that both Litres and Year are factors. I am going to plot `Litres`; but note that it uses a comma as a decimal point. I change this using:

```
df$Litres <- as.numeric(gsub(",", "\\.", as.character(df$Litres)))
```

We see that `Year` is not really a year, but a two-year range stored as a character. When R reads a character such as "1960-61", it does not understand what this means. We can do a lot of re-formatting here, or something even simpler: assuming there are no repeated time intervals, I create a simple sequence from 1 to the end of your dataframe:

```
df$yr <- 1:nrow(df)
```

This gives me:

```
head(df, 3)
     Year Litres PerCapita yr
1 1960-61 67.703      9.34  1
2 1961-62 69.408      9.38  2
3 1962-63 71.657      9.47  3
```

Now, I use this one to plot one of your variables, suppressing the x-axis:

```
plot(df$yr, df$Litres, xaxt='n')
```

To get the x-axis with the appropriate labels (the year-ranges), we call `axis`:

```
axis(1, at = df$yr, labels = df$Year)
```

This gives you:

[image]

What has happened here is that we have created a plot with implicit x-axis labelling from 1 to n, but we have told `R` to use different labels for the x-axis ticks.

In case your years would be actual years and not weird ranges, the following would be another option:

```
# first, create the years:
df$yr <- substr(df$Year, 1,4)
# this gives us:
head(df)
     Year Litres PerCapita   yr
1 1960-61 67.703      9.34 1960
2 1961-62 69.408      9.38 1961
3 1962-63 71.657      9.47 1962
4 1963-64 75.590      9.79 1963
5 1964-65 79.674     10.10 1964
6 1965-66 80.866     10.00 1965

# now convert it to date, specifying the format:
df$yr_date <- as.Date(df$yr, format = "%Y")

head(df)
     Year Litres PerCapita   yr    yr_date
1 1960-61 67.703      9.34 1960 1960-08-21
2 1961-62 69.408      9.38 1961 1961-08-21
3 1962-63 71.657      9.47 1962 1962-08-21
```

This can now be plotted:

```
plot(df$yr_date, df$Litres)
```

[image]

Alternatively, with these years, you could also do

```
df$yr_num <- as.numeric(df$yr)
plot(df$yr_num, df$Litres)
```

Answer (score 0):

You defined x as follows:

```
> x=c(1960-61,1961-62,1962-63,1963-64,1964-65,1965-66,1966-67,1967-68,1968-
  69,1969-70,1970-71,1971-72,1972-73,1973-74,1974-75,1975-76,1976-77,1977-
  78,1978-79,1979-80,1980-81,1981-82,1982-83,1983-84,1984-85,1985-86,1986-
  87,1987-88,1988-89,1989-90,1990-91,1991-92,1992-93,1993-94,1994-95,1995-
  96,1996-97,1997-98,1998-99,1999-2000,2000-01,2001-02,2002-03,2003-04,2004-
  05,2005-06,2006-07,2007-08,2008-09,2009-10,2010-11,2011-12,2012-13,2013-14)
```

This is a vector of equations: 1960-61 = 1899, 1961-62=1899, ..., 1999-2000 = -1, 2000-01 = 1999, ... 2013-14 = 1999.

As a result, your plot has one point at x = -1, a bunch of points at x = 1899, and another bunch at x = 1999.

Try the following instead? It's not the most optimal code, but it's close to what you already have, so it should be easy to understand:

```
# Year & Litres should be based on your dataset. No manipulation needed.
Year <- Alcohol_consumption_2013_14$Year
Litres <- Alcohol_consumption_2013_14$`Litres Pure Alcohol`

barplot(Litres, names.arg = Year)
plot(factor(Year), Litres)
```